# How to change default port of rocket chat server installed using docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rocket.chat

I have used docker to install Rocket.Chat on my instance. By default it runs on port number 3000 but i want to run it on the other port.

My docker-compose.yml file looks like: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml

How can i run it on different port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the port mapping between the host and the container. Just update the docker-comopse file and change the following section:

```
ports:
  - <host-port>:3000
```

Just update the `<host-port>` above to the port that you want.

Answer (score 3):

**Running with command:**

```
docker container run -p Your_desired_local_port:3000 rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
```

but rocket chat require mongo to be running first so you have to have a running mongo-db container on the same network or you do a docker-compose.

**Running with docker-compose**
 you just need to add the new port in docker-compose file in below mentioned places.

```
 services:
  rocketchat:
    image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      - PORT=  ADD THE NEW PORT HERE
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:ADD THE NEW PORT HERE
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/rocketchat
      - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/local
      - MAIL_URL=smtp://smtp.email
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - ADD THE NEW PORT HERE:3000
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=rocketchat"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host: your.domain.tld"
```

Answer (score 1):

just change the port that related to your `rocketchat` service to your desired port, for instance, if you wanna use port `8181`

`services:
  rocketchat:
    image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      - PORT=8181
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:8181`

...

    `ports:
      - 8181:8181`

...

    `restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ROCKETCHAT_URL=rocketchat:8181`

and change all `3000` port to `8181`

let me know if its doesnt work